# How to open the lightbulb via shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Some languages support code actions which display a lightbulb providing quick fixes for a warning/error (See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_code-action for more information). 
I like this feature but I don't like to click on the lightbulb. Unfortunately I can't find a **shortcut for opening the lightbulb at the current cursor position**. 
How can I create such a shortcut?

I tried to create a shortcut for `vscode.executeCodeActionProvider` by creating a custom keybinding like this:

```
[{ "key": "alt+enter", "command": "vscode.executeCodeActionProvider"}]
```

But everytime I hit the shortcut I receive the warning

> Running the contributed command:'vscode.executeCodeActionProvider' failed.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

The correct command `editor.action.quickFix`. The default binding on Windows looks like this:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+.", "command": "editor.action.quickFix",
                   "when": "editorTextFocus" }
```

On Mac it's <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 76):

If you're a JetBrains junkie and can't imagine not hammering on <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> all day long, then you can re-map the default (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>) easily enough.

Open the *File* menu and select *Preferences* then *Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Type `editor.action.quickFix` into the search box:

[image]

Click the pen icon, or right-click and select *Change Keybinding*.

Enter your preferred shortcut into the dialog that appears, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

You should end up with something that looks like:

[image]

Comment: Great. exactly what I was looking for. After adding auto TS import, this is a really important milestone for vscode competing with webstorm/intellij in terms of js/ts ide. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: What do you mean with "not hammering on Alt+Enter all day long", is `alt+enter` the default to show quick fix?

Comment: @Timo in JetBrains products, Alt+Enter is a shortcut that invokes a lot of actions.