# Vscode keyboard shortcut for the bell

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

There is a keyboard shortcut for showing the "bell" options?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Ctrl + .`

you can see other shortcuts here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_rich-languages-editing

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered here: [How to open the lightbulb via shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34020340/how-to-open-the-lightbulb-via-shortcut). The keyboard shortcut by default is <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>